# Why character can't print after 128 number

Tags: java, charts, binary

In my project i am try to convert Binary number to integer and convert integer to Character. But after 128 number print only '?' character. Please help me how to print up to 250 characters. My code is

```
 class b 
  {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
                        String dec1="11011001" ;

                        System.out.println(dec1);
                        int dec = Integer.parseInt(dec1, 2);
                        System.out.println(dec);
                        String str = new Character((char)dec).toString();
                        System.out.println("decrypted number is "+str);
    }
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of terminal are you viewing the results on?

Comment: The proper term is "decoded" not "decrypted". Character encoding is a simple mapping between an element of a character set (a codepoint or "character") and a sequence of code units (each stored as a number of bytes). The only "key" is the name of the encoding, which, although it must be agreed upon by sender and receiver, it is not a secret key kept only to them, so encoding does not have the same purpose as encryption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all byte values have a printable character associated with them, ASCII does not, many/most unicode bytes do not, and the range 0x00 - 0x1f are all unprintable controls such as DC1, Bell, Backspace, etc. Unicode has the same first 32 characters reserved as non-printable.

Byte values above 127 (0x7f) have different meanings in different encodings, there are many encodings. Historically ASCII was the default encoding and there were many extensions to it. These days the standard is unicode which exists in several varieties including UTF-8, UTF-16 (LE, BE and BOM) and UTF-32 (LE, BE and BOM). UTF8 is common for interchange especially over the net and UTF-16 internally in many systems.

Depending on the encoding and glyph (displayed representation) it may take from one to over 16 bytes to represent a single glyph. Emoji mostly are in code plane 1 meaning that they require more than 16-bits for their code point (unicode is a 21-bit encoding system). Additionally some glyphs are represented by a sequence of code points, examples are flags which combine a country with the flag and Emoji joined with "joiners".

In the case of 217 (0xd9) that is not a legal codepoint in UTF-8 but 217 as two bytes (16-bit integer) (0x00d9) is a valid representation of `Ù`.

See [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode).

Comment: "Historically ASCII was the default encoding": perhaps in the 1970s but not in the PC-era/arena. "These days the standard is unicode": Yes, since the beginning of Java, .NET, JavaScript, XML DOM, NTFS, HTML 4 DOM, VB 6, Windows NT 3.51 (or before?), …, …, …—practically any new interoperable thing since 1991 has started with Unicode or corrected that mistake. In other words, non-Unicode is a special case and, besides, history is moot because any text communication (stream) or store (file) has to use exactly one encoding and everyone has to know what it is.

Comment: Yes, in the '70's, pre-PCs with the exception of IBM and EPCIDIC. That is where I come from and all we had was ASCII only upper case only at that. There still is poor support for unicode above plane 0.

Comment: From Wikipedia [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8): One-byte codes are used only for the ASCII values 0 through 127. In this case the UTF-8 code has the same value as the ASCII code. The high-order bit of these codes is always 0. This means that ASCII text is valid UTF-8, and UTF-8 can be used for parsers expecting 8-bit extended ASCII even if they are not designed for UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your console's encoding doesn't match the encoding of the output of your Java program. I don't know what console you're using, but on Windows, you can run this command to see your current encoding:

```
chcp
```

The default console's encoding for USA is 437 and for Western Europe and Canada 850. These encodings have the 128 characters from ASCII encoding and 128 additional characters that are different from one encoding to another. You get nothing beyond the 128 ASCII characters because your Java output's encoding doesn't match the console's encoding. You have to change one of them to match the other.

You can change your console's encoding to UTF-8 by running this command:

```
chcp 65001
```

If you're not on Windows, you'll have to search for the equivalent commands for your system. But I believe on most Linux & Unix derived systems, you can use the `locale` command to see the current encoding and the `export` command to change it.

Comment: There are not 128 printable ASCII characters, the range 0x00 - 0x1f and 0x7f are all unprintable, see [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Comment: @zaph Where did I say that there were 128 printable characters in ASCII? Read carefully before you comment.

Comment: Your comment at 2016-08-28 14:05:03Z—most of it—should be your answer. The first paragraph of your answer implies that the asker's console's code page is ASCII, which is extremely unlikely. But whatever it is, he would benefit by changing it with `chcp` (Windows) or `locale` (Linux) and checking that the console's font supports both the code page and the characters desired. (The first part of the second paragraph of the answer is irrelevant to the runtime behavior of the program.)

Comment: @TomBlodget Thanks for the very useful comment. I've updated the answer accordingly. However, why do you think that *the asker's console's code page is ASCII, which is extremely unlikely*? It is actually very likely, and that's exactly what I was trying to say. The default console encoding on all personal Windows (i.e. other than NT and Server) is some form of ASCII. See my updated answer for more details.

Comment: Well, there is only one form of ASCII that is the code page called ASCII.

Comment: @TomBlodget OK, I see what you mean. You're being very accurate :-). I've updated my answer again to make it clearer. Thank you. These encodings are commonly called **Extended ASCII**. ASCII is 7bit encoding, and those encodings are 8bit that include 128 characters additional to the ASCII 128 characters. I'm sure you know the history of encoding, so I will stop here and just refer to [Wikipedia about the term Extended ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII).

Answer (score 2):

As per your code,First the binary will be converted to Integer and Then you are converting Integer to the Character which is done by checking the ASCII value. 
 It will return the character having same ASCII value as the Integer `dec1` you are converting. Since in [ASCII TABLE](http://www.asciitable.com/) the values are upto 127, You will get the character upto the integer value 127, So for the greater value of `dec1` than 127, You will get character as `?` which will be then converted into String. 
 
First 32 elements are non-printable characters so you will get some strange symbol for it but for value of `dec1` in the range 32-126, You will get the character assigned to that particular ASCII value as per [ASCII TABLE](http://www.asciitable.com/). Since the value 127 is assigned to DEL, you will get strange symbol for value of `dec` 127.

Comment: Java doesn't use ASCII. See [Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html).

Answer (score -1):

I receive the following output from your code. I assume that you run the program in an environment/console that doesn't support the character. You need a console that support UTF-8, UTF-16 or similar to be able to print all characters you setup numerical values for.

```
11011001
217
decrypted number is Ù
```

Comment: @Kecon: I think `Ù` is not utf-8 - it's (probably) latin-1.

Comment: in[UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) 11011001 (0xd9) is not a UTF-8 character, it is the introduction to a multi-byte code point. That seems to be UTF-16, an encoding used by many systems. See [Unicode Character 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH GRAVE' (U+00D9)](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAUDIOTAGGER-217)

Comment: The issue here is that he is unable to print characters above 128., he manage to transform the binary value into 217, and 217 from int to char will be converted into UTF-16, http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00D9/index.htm

Comment: All internal strings in Java are UTF-16 and will be converted upon print. Which means that a console with support for UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 or UTF-16 would be able to print the character.

Comment: Try 0x00d9 - 0xd9 in Google and see the result.

The transformation is when he goes from int to char.

Comment: @jcoppens Ù exist in UTF-8, the conversion is however when he read the value as an integer and the convert it to a char (UTF-16). It will not look like that when reading UTF-8 from a file, but he isn't. The problem here is that he focus why he get '?' when he print 217 as a character.

Comment: Yes, `Ù` exists in UTF-8 as a two byte code point: 0xC3 0x99.

Comment: @zaph 

`int dec = Integer.parseInt(dec1, 2);` set dec to 217
`String str = new Character((char) dec).toString();` where integer dec get converted to char which use 217 as UTF-16, which is Ù.

The conversion will be handled when the character is printed onto screen.